# Select2 is being duplicated in my component

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, jquery-select2

I am using the jquery plugin in my pages e until now i have not any problem with it. the problem happend when i am tring using the select2 with a ascx page. More description of the problem below.

I have a aspx that i am using a component ascx to show somethings:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" 
   MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback="True" AutoEventWireup="true" 
   CodeBehind="Register.aspx.cs" Inherits="Organization.Register" %>
<%@ Register Src="../DialogUF.ascx" TagPrefix="comp" TagName="DialogUF" %>

<asp:Content runat="server">
     <asp:LinkButton ID="btnUF" runat="server" CausesValidation="False"  
          OnClick="btnUF_Click">aqui</asp:LinkButton>
     <Comp:DialogUF ID="dlgUF" runat="server" />
</asp:Content>
```

In My code behind:

```
protected void btnUF_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dlgUF.Visible = true;
    }
```

Mas ascx:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="DialogUF.ascx.cs"
    Inherits="Organization.DialogUF" %>

...
<asp:Panel ID="pnlBody" runat="server">
<fieldset class="grid-form">
    <div data-row-span="12">
        <div data-field-span="6">
            <asp:Label runat="server" AssociatedControlID="ddlState">UF 
            <span class="text-danger">(*)</span>:</asp:Label>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlState" runat="server"
                CssClass="form-control" 
                OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddState_SelectedIndexChanged"
                AutoPostBack="True">
            </asp:DropDownList>
        </div>
    </div>
</fieldset>
...
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#<%= ddlState.ClientID %>").select2();
           });
</script>
</asp:Panel>
```

[Image of select2 duplicated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sdEds.png)

Comment: Can you comment out the initialization of select2 and show the client-side HTML code?

Comment: I commented the line that calls the select2 and the ascx component show me ONLY ONE DropDownList.